# delete old swap partition

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a second swap partition safely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45254/how-to-delete-a-second-swap-partition-safely)

I had this old swap partition  then I deleted my old Ubuntu partition and then installed Ubuntu 11.10 but it made another swap partition now I want to identify and delete the old swap partition
how to do it?

Comment: This has already been covered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45254/how-to-delete-a-second-swap-partition-safely