# got /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot in ubuntu 12.10 server virtual machine

Tags: command-line, automount, fsck

## Problem

I have this message called `/dev/sda1/ will be checked for errors at next reboot` when I booted up my VM running on ubuntu 12.10 server edition.

My host OS is mac os x lion.

## What I have tried

I have googled and found this [How can I get rid of the motd message "*** /dev/sdb1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141509/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-motd-message-dev-sdb1-will-be-checked-for-errors)

I tried `sudo mv /var/run/motd /var/run/motd.old` to force a clear of the current `/etc/motd` file as recommended in the first answer. No good.

`cat /etc/fstab` gives me:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=18946e20-7bc6-40f3-b486-e46394546202 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

This is what I got after I typed `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="18946e20-7bc6-40f3-b486-e46394546202" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="cXGZ2V-pdtX-A0sr-7uXp-elvC-vbgY-c70hDZ" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-root: UUID="260b3094-5f4a-4839-9108-30ea0323393c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-swap_1: UUID="d8228f3c-80da-44df-9555-8be04129bf5b" TYPE="swap"
```

I also tried

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

Didn't work.

I saw this http://www.iloveubuntu.net/how-repair-swap-partition-ubuntu but since I am running server edition I have no GUI.

Please advise.

Thank you.

## UPDATE

Weirdly enough, the message is now gone. I have no idea why after I shut down my host OS.

This question is still open so that someone could help explain why this is the case.